# Call Interrupt on thread working very slow

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, interrupt

I have one ConcurrentHashMap where I store threads that send some data to socket and that wait for response.

```
public class MyThreadSocketAsync implements Runnable
```

Inside that thread I have:

```
// add to hashmap
SocketHandler.getInstance().addThread(this, Thread.currentThread());

// send data
this.sendData();
 log.info("goToSleep");

//go to sleep
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (Exception t) {
}
log.info ("Thread awaken");
```

where in SocketHandler I have:

```
public void addThread(MyThreadSocketAsync t, Thread thread) {
    String threadIdS = generateThreadKey(t.getThreadId());
    threadList.put(threadIdS, new Object[] { t, thread });
}
```

Now I have different thread that read some data from socket and decide which thread should awake based on unique threadId.

```
public void releaseThread(String threadId, String returnValue) {
  Object[] o = threadList.remove(threadId);
  MyThreadSocketAsync t = o != null ? (MyThreadSocketAsync) o[0] : null;
  if (t != null) {
    t.setReturnValue(returnValue, threadId);
    ((Thread) o[1]).interrupt();
     log.info ("Awake thread");
  }
}
```

Problem is that between two logs "Awake thread" and "Thread awaken" some time I have more than 5 - 20 seconds. Seems that when I execute interrupt on Thread, it is not executed immediately. Now important is that this happens from time to time (specially when we have more than one concurrent thread executing on the system).
Question is why sometimes interrupt do not work immediately?

Log from production server:

```
25.10.2019 13:29:30.207  [DEBUG]  163133 > logMemoryUsageInfo : Total memory used: 23877 KB, free memory:37562 KB, JVM threadCount:17
25.10.2019 13:29:30.207  [INFO ]  163133 > MyThreadSocketAsync.run : Message received, concurentThreads:5
25.10.2019 13:29:30.211  [INFO ]  163133 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : length:40, hex:08008220000****
25.10.2019 13:29:30.211  [INFO ]  163133 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : ECHO message received
25.10.2019 13:29:30.211  [INFO ]  163133 > SocketHandler.addThread : key=0000163133, threadList.size=8
25.10.2019 13:29:30.211  [INFO ]  163133 > SocketHandler.sendMessage : messageToSend=0000163133101****
25.10.2019 13:29:30.211  [DEBUG]  163133 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : goToSleep
25.10.2019 13:29:30.258  [INFO ]  163133 > SocketHandler.releaseThread : Awake thread key=0000163133, threadList.size=12
25.10.2019 13:30:32.304  [DEBUG]  163133 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : Thread Awaken=62093 msec
25.10.2019 13:30:32.305  [DEBUG]  163133 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : Exit thread
```

Also there is another strange behavior, that may be related to this.

There are also situations that Thread is awaken after 20 msec, but not with my interrupt() method, but something else (system, GC, ..) interrupt thread, so In my log I have only:

```
25.10.2019 13:24:57.011  [DEBUG]  162448 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : goToSleep
25.10.2019 13:24:57.026  [DEBUG]  162448 > MyThreadSocketAsync.handleMessage : Thread Awaken=15 msec
```

I have no idea why this happens from time to time?

For thread executing I use threadPool:

```
threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 500, 1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
...
MyThreadSocketAsync cc = new MyThreadSocketAsync(messageCount, receivedMessage);
threadPool.execute(cc);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the interrupted thread is in a `sleep()` call when interrupted? If it is still sending data, it won't be interrupted until it attempts to call `sleep()`. Put a log statement immediately before the call to `sleep()` to see the relative order of events.

Comment: But even you are right, thread sleep for 5 sec, and awaken log written after 20 sec some time?

Comment: No. The thread works sending data for 20 seconds (or more). Then the thread tries to sleep but finds that its interrupt flag is set, and throws `InterruptedException`. This is swallowed (without restoring the interruption state), and then logs "Thread awaken", even though it never slept.

Comment: I checked log and added more comments to post. It is not a problem with sending. I'm programming in Java more than 15 years, and never had this kind of problem. As you may see, above I have 62 seconds delay!? Maybe this problem is related to processor on virtual PC (they had some problem with it around 14:45 same day, and they see in logs that virtual server tried to replace problematic CPU with new one, but that was around 14:45, and this problem was before

Comment: Are you interrupting the right one? `((Thread) o[1]).interrupt()` isn't it supposed to be `o[0]` ?

Comment: yes I do. I analyzed log, and let say, I have 20 000 transaction per hour, and only one where sleep time exceeded 5000 msec and  96 transactions where thread is awaken before 5 000 msec (but awaken by something else, not me). Other 19 003 working as expected.

Comment: o[0] is interface that implements Thread (used to set return value from third party system), and o[1] is reference to thread.

Comment: An `interrupt()` call is synchronous; when it returns, the other thread has "received" the interrupt. But that doesn't mean the receiving thread is going to do anything about it immediately. It could be blocked in non-interruptible I/O, or simply executing code that doesn't check for interruption. The additional logs are helpful, but you might also log if `sleep()` is interrupted. Right now, there's no evidence to show the interrupt is received "late"; you sleep for 5 seconds but see 60 second delays. It may be that the thread isn't getting scheduled to run because the system is too busy.

Comment: So you think that this is not related somehow with ThreadPool?

Comment: And what about sleep() that is interrupted before defined sleep time. Why this happened?

Comment: The fast wake ups could be that the thread already has been interrupted erroneously when it enters `sleep()`. E.g., a previous interaction interrupted the thread too late, after `sleep()` completes. I’m *not* saying that there isn’t a problem with the thread pool. You are using the executor in an unconventional way, submitting tasks that run forever and interrupting its threads directly instead of cancelling the task. I can only speculate with essentially no code.

Comment: Also, if you are responding to a comment, use @ to notify the person.

Comment: @erickson Executors are used in normal way. When transaction is received I start task with execute(cc). When task send data to third party it goes to sleep. When response is received from third party, task is interrupted with received value and finish transaction by returning response to a sender and task finished. So one transaction - one task. Regarding comment related to system busy and 60 seconds - I have other transactions working in background during this 60 seconds, so make no sense that sleep(5000) awake after 60 sec.

Comment: That’s not a typical usage. You are using `sleep()` and `interrupt()` instead of `wait()` and `notify()`. Blocking one executor thread to wait for the response to return to the sender seems strange too. Why not submit another task for that, and keep fewer threads more busy? Anyway, good luck.